# gcp cloud function - set minimum instances with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to set minimum number of my function instances to 1 with terraform. However when I apply such syntax ([terraform docx](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function#min_instances)):

```
module "my_function" {
  source                = "xxxx"
  source_dir            = "${local.repo_root}/src"
  name                  = "xxxx"
  service_account_email = module.service_account.email
  runtime               = "dotnet6"
  entrypoint            = "xxx"
  min_instances         = 1 
  environment_variables = ...
}
```

when building with Google Cloud Build I get the following error:

```
Step #1 - "Deploy": │ Error: Unsupported argument
Step #1 - "Deploy": │ 
Step #1 - "Deploy": │   on ../../modules/main/main.tf line 39, in module "my_function":
Step #1 - "Deploy": │   39:   min_instances         = 1 
Step #1 - "Deploy": │ 
Step #1 - "Deploy": │ An argument named "min_instances" is not expected here.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your module? Can you share its type or its definition? It's sound more an issue on your side than on Google/terraform side.

Comment: I didn't set up the entire thing, I'm not good at terraform... this one I found in "environments" fodler: ```module "main" {
  source  = "../../modules/main"
  project = var.project
  env     = var.env
}```

Comment: This doesn't tell us nothing. As @guillaumeblaquiere mentioned we may need to know the definition of the module `my_function`. If you're not good at terraform then you should first read the documentation to understand what you're doing https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules. The issue is not with GCP, is with the definition of the module

Comment: yeah, indeed the definition was on a different repo and `min_instances` was not listed there, I added it and now it works fine. Thanks for your hints @guillaumeblaquiere & @Puteri

Comment: @adam.k, please post your answer so that it would be helpful to other community members with similar concerns.

Answer (score 0):

As per @guillaumeblaquiere and @Puteri, the module definition must be defined as it would produce `Unsupported argument` error. You may first refer to this documentation on [Terraform Modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules) for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The arg `min_instances` does not appear to be supported in the system you're using. This means that it is either not a valid argument for the module you're using (module "my_function") or it is not supported by the underlying package or environment.

Once solution could be autoscaling. It will allow you to automatically adjust the number of instances based on your criteria, to ensure that the minimum and maximum instances are maintained. In HCL code, using Node.js version 14, this would look something like

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "my_function" {
  name       = "my-function"
  runtime    = "nodejs14"
  entry_point = "myFunction"

  # Other config...

  scaling_policy {
    min_instances = 1
    max_instances = 10
    target_cpu_utilization = 0.6
  }
}
```

Define the `scaling_policy` block where we set the `min_instances` to 1 to ensure at least one instance is always running.

Answer (score 0):

following **Peter G**'s comment, here's what I had to do.

Indeed, there was a `cloud_function` module I had, but it was in another github repo. What I had to do was 2 things:

1. In `terraform-modules/cloud_function /main.tf` file:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function" {
  name    = var.name
  ...

  min_instances = var.min_instances

  ...
  }
}
```

2. And in `terraform-modules/cloud_function/variables.tf` file:

```
variable "min_instances" {
  type        = number
  default     = 0
  description = "you can increase availability of a function by setting this at least to 1"
}
```

Only then I could use the `min_instances` variable how I did in the question.

What misled me here, was that I was using a custom-made module, and not just terraform gcp's resource. The resource has `min_instances` var available, but it wasn't specified in the module.